# How to identify text within an object's string

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to find specified text within a string in a given column, and count how many times that string is repeated throughout the entire column.

For example, Find "XX" within a string in a column and print to dialogue box the number of times that text was found.

```
Module m = current
Object o

    string s
    string x
    int offset = null
    int len    = null
    int c
    
for o in m do
{
    string s = probeAttr_(o, "AttributeA")
    
    
        x = o."Object Text" ""
    if(findPlainText(s, "XX", offset, len, false)){

        print "Success "

    } else {

        print "Failed to match"

    }
}
```

I have tried to use command findPlainText but I am inadvertently passing every object as true.
As well I placed the output to print 'success' or 'Failed to match' so I can at least get a number count of what is being passed. Unfortunately it seems like everything is being passed!

My understanding is that 'probeAttr_(o, "AttributeA")' allows me to specify and enter what column to search. As well o."Object Text" "" now allows me to look within any object and search for any text contained. I also realize that variable x is not being used but assume it has some way of being used to solve this issue.

I only use DOORS at a surface level but having this ability will save other staff tons of time. I realize this may be accomplished using the DOORS advanced filtering capability but I'd be able to compound this code with other simple commands to save time.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: In addition: please be strict in your wording when you work with DOORS. An "attribute" is something that contains a value. Objects and Modules have attributes, the attributes are defined in the module.
A "column" is something that is shown in a view. The column may show the the content of an attribute or other things like calculated values.

Comment: Also note that "Object Text" is only one attribute. A typical, non customized module has at least the object attributes "Object Text" and "Object Heading". A productive module usually has lots of attributes. So you might want to review your requirement whether you want to look at each and every attribute defined in the module or only at Object Text.

Comment: Wow I have a lot to improve on! Will do in the future and thank you!

Comment: If you received an answer to your question, please mark the question as "answered'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count every occurence of a specified string in a text in an attribute for all objects, I think Mike's proposal is the correct answer. If you are only interested, if the specified string occurs once in that object's attribute, I suggest using Regexp, as I find it very fast, quite powerful and nevertheless easy to use, e.g.:

```
Regexp reSearch = regexp2 "XX"
int iCounter = 0
string strOT = ""
for o in m do {
  strOT = o."Object Text" ""
  if (reSearch strOT) {
    iCounter++
  }
}
print "Counted: '" iCounter "'\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of this has been answered in [(DXL/Doors) How to find and count a text in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567115/dxl-doors-how-to-find-and-count-a-text-in-a-string)
You can easily exchange the "print" with a counter.